# Como selecionar dados que dependem de outras tabelas que têm uma outra chave em comum?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, inner-join

Olá! Eu estava trabalhando em um projeto de Banco de Dados usando a linguagem SQL no MySQL Workbench. O cenário do meu projeto é uma biblioteca universitária em que temos as tabelas: (**Negrito = PK** | *Itálico = FK*)

- `Emprestimo(`**`ID_emprestimo`**`,` *`ID_funcionario`*`, data_emprestimo)`
- `Emprestimo_Livro(`*`ID_emprestimo`*`,` *`ID_livro`*`, data_devolucao_livro)`
- `Livro(`**`ID_livro`**`, titulo, ISBN, formato, edicao, ano_da_edicao, paginas,` *`ID_acervo`*`,` *`ID_editora`*`)`
- `Emprestimo_Trabalho_Academico(`*`ID_emprestimo`*`,` *`ID_trabalho_academico`*`, data_devolucao_trabalho_academico)`
- `Trabalho_Academico(`**`ID_trabalho_academico`**`, titulo, ano_de_publicacao, matricula_professor,` *`ID_acervo`*`)`
- `Acervo(`**`ID_acervo`**`, campus)`

Eu gostaria de selecionar uma informação a partir destas tabelas: *"Todos os empréstimos de um acervo"*. Estas são as únicas tabelas que têm relação com as chaves que eu preciso para alcançar os empréstimos de materiais que pertencem a um acervo.

A tabela `Emprestimo` contém todos os empréstimos feitos, enquanto a tabelas `Emprestimo_Livro` e Emprestimo_Trabalho_Academico possuem os empréstimos de seus respectivos materiais e a identidade destes materiais. 
Por sua vez, as tabelas `Livro` e `Trabalho_Academico` possuem a chave primária de `Acervo`, que é o acervo de onde pertencem. Eu estava tentando selecionar todos os materiais de um determinado acervo desta forma (*mas sem sucesso*):

```
SELECT Emprestimo.ID_emprestimo
    FROM 
        Emprestimo
    INNER JOIN
        emprestimo_livro ON Emprestimo.ID_emprestimo = emprestimo_livro.ID_emprestimo
    INNER JOIN
        emprestimo_trabalho_academico ON Emprestimo.ID_emprestimo = emprestimo_trabalho_academico.ID_emprestimo
    INNER JOIN
        Livro ON Livro.ID_acervo = Acervo.ID_acervo
    INNER JOIN
        Trabalho_Academico ON Trabalho_Academico.ID_acervo = Acervo.ID_acervo
    WHERE
        Acervo.ID_acervo = 'C100';
```

Agora já estou sem ideias, não sei como selecionar os empréstimos de livros E trabalhos acadêmicos que pertençam ao mesmo acervo. Qualquer ajuda será grandemente apreciada! Obrigado!

Comment: Vá por partes: Faça a consulta de todos os emprestimos que contenham um livro que este livro pertença a um acervo. Sequência dos JOINs: Emprestimo ->  emprestimo_livro -> livro -> acervo `WHERE  Acervo.ID_acervo = 'C100';` Quando obtiver esse resultado,, faça uma consulta semelhante para trabalho acadêmico. Depois faça uma união das consultas por meio do `UNION`. O Maior problema na sua consulta atual é que não está fazendo junção `inner join` com a tabela Acervo. Tente mais um pouco e informe o que conseguiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certo, neste caso acredito que ajuda pensar com relações.

Alguns bancos nos permitem criar relações usando o [WITH statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), dessa forma podemos fazer algo assim:

```sql
WITH items_acervos AS (
    SELECT Livro.ID_acervo, 
           Livro.titulo,
           Livro.ID_livro referencia,
           'LIVRO' tipo,
           Emprestimo_Livro.ID_emprestimo
    FROM Livro
    JOIN Emprestimo_Livro ON Livro.ID_livro = Emprestimo_Livro.ID_livro
    UNION 
    SELECT Trabalho_Academico.ID_acervo, 
           Trabalho_Academico.titulo,
           Trabalho_Academico.ID_trabalho_academico referencia,
           'TRABALHO ACADEMICO' tipo,
           Emprestimo_Trabalho_Academico.ID_emprestimo
    FROM Trabalho_Academico
    JOIN Emprestimo_Trabalho_Academico ON Trabalho_Academico.ID_trabalho_academico = Emprestimo_Trabalho_Academico.ID_trabalho_academico
)
SELECT Emprestimo.ID_emprestimo,
       Emprestimo.ID_funcionario,
       items_acervos.tipo,
       items_acervos.titulo,
       items_acervos.referencia
FROM Emprestimo 
JOIN items_acervos ON items_acervos.ID_emprestimo = Emprestimo.ID_emprestimo
JOIN Acervo ON Acervo.ID_acervo = items_acervos.ID_acervo AND 
               Acervo.ID_acervo = 'C100'
```

Nesse caso o que fizemos foi criar uma relação que representa os empréstimos dos itens emprestados, independente se são livros ou trabalhos acadêmicos, nesta relação incluímos informações comuns a ambas as entidades, como titulo, id de referencia e uma coluna para informar o tipo.

Tendo esta relação podemos fazer um select com um JOIN com a tabela Emprestimos para obter os funcionários e com a tabela Acervo se quisermos trazer mais alguma informação, como o nome do acervo, categoria, etc.

#### Consideração

Um ponto positivo desta abordagem, é que se no futuro, por exemplo, você vier a ter um conjunto de tabelas como `Material_AudioVisual` e `Emprestimo_Material_AudioVisual` você pode adicionar um select para elas dentro da relação `items_acervos`, sem ter que modificar o resto da consulta.

Comment: Essa ideia funcionou muito bem!!! Muito obrigado. Eu só tenho algumas perguntas... 
Por que usar o JOIN em vez de INNER JOIN?  
O que significa o `'LIVRO' tipo` e o `'TRABALHO_ACADEMICO' tipo`? Fazem o papel das _Common Table Expressions_ (CTEs) que li na documentação?   
De qualquer maneira, muitíssimo obrigado por sua resposta, é uma ideia que eu achei genial, muito didática inclusive! Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Nick, certo, uma coisa que gosto de pensar são em relações, o CTE no fim acaba virando uma relação, dessa forma ao declarar a coluna ```'LIVRO'``` tipo e ```'TRABALHO_ACADEMICO'``` eu estou criando uma nova coluna chamada tipo na relação, no qual ela pode ter um desses 2 valores, isso pode ajudar você a identificar o que é o que quando selecionar. Quanto ao INNER JOIN bancos que usam o padrão [SQL92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) assumem que um JOIN não especificado é um INNER JOIN, o INNER é mais explícito.

Comment: Quando você cria uma relação você tem controle sobre as colunas e valores que serão retornados, e esse conceito (o de relação) é muito importante, assim como o conceito de projeção, visto que estamos projetando a relação que precisamos, não necessariamente a relação que está armazenada em banco.

Comment: Poxa vida! Faz muito sentido, obrigado por explicar tudo @ooredroxoo! Com certeza vou pensar mais assim dessa maneira nas próximas implementações. Muito obrigado!